# Error was retrieving data from S3 using boto for python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to get data from Amazon S3 using boto for python.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_KEY = 'MY_KEY'
AWS_SECRET = 'MY_SECRET'
aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('s3://mybucket.buckets.com/')
for file_key in bucket.list():
    print file_key.name
```

I'm passing a valid Key, secret_key and Bucketname.

When I try executing the above code I'm getting the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyPython_Script.py", line 7, in <module>
    bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('s3://mybucket.buckets.com/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 506, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 525, in head_bucket
    response = self.make_request('HEAD', bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 668, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Any idea how to overcome this error ? Is my format used to pass the bucket name correct ?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to pass the name of you bucket, not a seamless URL (note that s3 endpoint would be http://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/bucket)

If you're using boto2

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_KEY = 'MY_KEY'
AWS_SECRET = 'MY_SECRET'
aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('bucket_name', validate=False)
for file_key in bucket.list():
    print file_key.name
```

If you're using boto3

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('name')
```